# How to handle plugins of two different QGIS installations on the same computer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante

I have a computer with 2 versions of QGIS. Both versions are running on Win 7 64 bits with 16 Mb of ram. One is Dufour 32 bits and the other one is version 2.1 OSgeo4W 64 bits.

I am experimenting using the processing menu on both versions.  Nevertheless I noticed that the paths for Grass in my 2.01 32 bits version were the ones of the OSgeo4W install (Processing/Options and configuration/Providers). I changed to the Dufour ones.

Then I tried to replicate a procedure in my 64 bit install but the paths were the Dufour ones!

My question is, then, how I can handle the settings for each install in order that they are independent from each other and I do not have to change my provider paths each time that I want to use the processing menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cool little trick with QGIS is being able to isolate all the user files and folders along with all the settings into a different location.

QGIS can be started with the `--configpath` and `--optionspath` swtiches to redirect any of the settings or options to a different folder.

An example of doing that with QGIS 2.0 is:

```
SET QGIS=%PROGRAMFILES%\QGIS Dufour
SET args=--optionspath %~dp0\myqgis64options --configpath %~dp0\myqgis64config
"%QGIS%\bin\nircmd.exe" exec hide "%QGIS%\bin\qgis.bat" %args%
```

*Note:* I have just made them into variables here to make it a bit easier to work with. I will still work if you have it all on one line:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\bin\nircmd.exe" exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin\qgis.bat --optionspath %~dp0\myqgis64options --configpath %~dp0\myqgis64config
```

`optionspath` and `configpath` can be the same folder if needed.

This is the result:

[image]

`myqgis64options` are all the settings, UI layouts, enabled toolbars, enabled plugins, etc
`myqgis64config` is the stuff you normally find in `.qgis2`

**TIP** You can just take a copy of the QGIS 2.0 shortcut on your desktop and add the `--optionspath` and `--configpath` options after that to save creating a batch file.

[image]

**EDIT** You also don't need to redirect both, you can use `--configpath` without needing to use `--optionspath`.

Comment: It works! Now I can have both installations really independent from each other.